# Custom Post Type Rewrite To Include Parent Page(s)

Tags: posts, rewrite-rules, customization

I have a page title "more" with subpage "cities-guide". Said "cities guide" page has a loop that pulls in posts from custom post type "thailife_city_guide".

My permalink structure is `/%category%/%postname%/`.

At present clicking a link to a custom post from 
 `www.mydomain.com/more/cities-guide gives`
 `www.mydomain.com/thailife_city_guide/bangkok` for example.

I want it to be displayed as `www.mydomain.com/more/cities-guide/bangkok` but cannot get anything to work

I tried fixing the rewrite in the CPT register to `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'more/cities-guide' )`, but to no avail, throws a 404.

Can someone please advise as I just dont really understand the way in which WordPress rewrite works so I am stumped?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to flush the permalink structure. You can either visit the settings->permalinks page or use flush_rewrite_rules() method.